# How to fix non-uniform scaling?

Tags: inkscape, resize

Let's say I have text with non-uniform scaling:

[image]

Does Inkscape have an easy and quick way to fix non-uniform scaling? Of course, I can scale it manually, but I'm looking for a quick and precise method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to revert a transformation (scale, rotation, skew) of any object back to its origina state, you have remove the `transform` matrix associated with the object.

This can be done in 2 ways:

1. Select the object
2. Open the XML editor ("<>" toolbar icon).
3. The `svg:text` element (or whatever object you selected) should have a `transform` attribute.
4. Delete this attribute.

2nd method:

1. Select the object.
2. *Object -> Transform*
3. Go to the *Matrix* tab.
4. Check the *Edit current matrix* option.
5. Press the *Clear* button to reset the matrix.
6. Press *Apply*.

Comment: This will also remove all non-scaling transformations like rotation or translation. Is the a way to avoid this (that does not involve copying the transformation matrix to a computer algebra system, doing the math and copying it back?