# Inkscape: Is there a way to unstretch / undistort text?

Tags: inkscape, text, scale

I'm working on an svg where all the text got condensed by someone scaling a bunch of items nonproportionally. All the text is still text and editable. Is there a way to select the text items and have them revert to the font's natural proportions?

Comment: Hi! There is a similar question here: [How to fix non-uniform scaling?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/130776/how-to-fix-non-uniform-scaling/130780#130780).

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

1. Select the text box with the Select and Transform tool <kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Open the XML editor using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
3. In the right pane of the XML editor, select the "Transform" item in the list.
4. In the settings box at the bottom right of the XML editor there will be a value that says "scale(xxx,xxx)". Delete everything in that box and click *Set*

Example showing what to delete

[image]

This will completely remove the transform.

Note: you may have to reposition the text as doing this will probably mess with the position co-ordinates. So, if the text position is important to you, you might want to place some guides so you can see where the text was, before removing the transform.

Comment: Clicking on the button at the top to delete the whole attribute is probably faster than deleting the text content?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! A couple of followups… 1) Is there any way to do this to multiple text items at once? 

2) Some of the items don't seem to have 'scale' in the transform attribute, rather 'matrix' and I can't delete that.

3)  it is really onerous to have to reposition the baseline for all these boxes. Is there any way to preserve the location?

Comment: @donutb For your first question, not as far as I know. Secondly, a matrix is just another way of transforming. You should still be able to select it and delete it in the same way. I know I can, not sure what's stopping you from doing so. And thirdly, as far as I know, there's no way to stop it messing up the positioning. Sorry about that.